# Smooth hover effect on multi-stages navigation bar in css

Tags: css

I have a multi-stages circles navigation bar in pure css. I want to achieve a hover effect but its not working smoothly. Its very jerky and ugly. How to make it smooth?

Can we also have a effect on hover where blue ball increases from 0 to full width gradually and then a white circle around it appears?

```css
#stages_cont {
margin:50px auto;
width:600px;
}

#stages {
background:#d4d7df;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:4px;
height:5px;
}

#stages li {
float:left;
text-align:center;
width:33%;
}

#stages li a {
-moz-border-radius:50%;
-webkit-border-radius:50%;
border-radius:50%;
display:block;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-decoration:none;
}

.stage_done .stage_circle {
background:#2585fe;
border:6px solid #ffffff;
box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #d4d7df;
height:20px;
width:20px;
margin:-13px auto 10px;
}

.stage_not .stage_circle {
background:#d4d7df;
height:20px;
width:20px;
margin:-8px auto 17px;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
transition:all 0.5s ease;
}

.stage_done .stage_link {
color:#2585fe;
}

.stage_not .stage_link {
color:#d4d7df;
}

.clr {
clear:both;
}

.stage_not:hover .stage_circle {
background:#2585fe;
border:6px solid #ffffff;
box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #d4d7df;
margin:-13px auto 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" />

<div id="stages_cont">
  <ul id="stages">
      <li class="stage_done">
          <a class="stage_circle" href="#"></a>
          <a class="stage_link" href="#">Details</a>
      </li>
      <li class="stage_done">
          <a class="stage_circle" href="#"></a>
          <a class="stage_link" href="#">Content</a>
      </li>
      <li class="stage_not">
          <a class="stage_circle" href="#"></a>
          <a class="stage_link" href="#">Send or Schedule</a>
      </li>
      <div class="clr"></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I have 2 options - first is to make this hover smooth, and second is to make this hover using some keyframe animation effect.

Answer (score 1):

Update the following styles

```
.stage_not .stage_circle {
  background: #d4d7df;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: -8px auto 17px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stage_not:hover .stage_circle {
  background: #2585fe;
  border: 6px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #d4d7df;
  margin: -13px auto 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
```

```css
#stages_cont {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 600px;
}

#stages {
  background: #d4d7df;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 5px;
}

#stages li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 33%;
}

#stages li a {
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stage_done .stage_circle {
  background: #2585fe;
  border: 6px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #d4d7df;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: -13px auto 10px;
}

.stage_not .stage_circle {
  background: #d4d7df;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: -8px auto 17px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stage_done .stage_link {
  color: #2585fe;
}

.stage_not .stage_link {
  color: #d4d7df;
}

.clr {
  clear: both;
}

.stage_not:hover .stage_circle {
  background: #2585fe;
  border: 6px solid #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #d4d7df;
  margin: -13px auto 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" />

<div id="stages_cont">
  <ul id="stages">
    <li class="stage_done">
      <a class="stage_circle" href="#"></a>
      <a class="stage_link" href="#">Details</a>
    </li>
    <li class="stage_done">
      <a class="stage_circle" href="#"></a>
      <a class="stage_link" href="#">Content</a>
    </li>
    <li class="stage_not">
      <a class="stage_circle" href="#"></a>
      <a class="stage_link" href="#">Send or Schedule</a>
    </li>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty much close to my requirement but if you keenly notice the hover effect then you will find that there is a fraction of jerk at the last moment when blue ball completes its dimension.

Comment: Sorry I cant notice it :(. Wait for some time may be someone can help you out better.

Answer (score 1):

Please change the css as on the given snippet

```css
#stages_cont {
margin:50px auto;
width:600px;
}

#stages {
background:#d4d7df;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:4px;
height:5px;
}

#stages li {
float:left;
text-align:center;
width:33%;
}

#stages li a {
-moz-border-radius:50%;
-webkit-border-radius:50%;
border-radius:50%;
display:block;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-decoration:none;
}

.stage_done .stage_circle {
background:#2585fe;
border:6px solid #ffffff;
box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #d4d7df;
height:20px;
width:20px;
margin:-13px auto 10px;
}

.stage_not .stage_circle {
       background: #d4d7df;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    /* margin: -8px auto 17px; */
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 40px;
}
li.stage_not {
  position: relative;
} 
.stage_done .stage_link {
color:#2585fe;
}

.stage_not .stage_link {
color:#d4d7df;
}

.clr {
clear:both;
}

.stage_not:hover .stage_circle {
background:#2585fe;
border:6px solid #ffffff;
box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #d4d7df;
}
.stage_not a.stage_link {
      padding-top: 29px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css" />
<div id="stages_cont">
  <ul id="stages">
      <li class="stage_done">
          <a class="stage_circle" href="#"></a>
          <a class="stage_link" href="#">Details</a>
      </li>
      <li class="stage_done">
          <a class="stage_circle" href="#"></a>
          <a class="stage_link" href="#">Content</a>
      </li>
      <li class="stage_not">
          <a class="stage_circle" href="#"></a>
          <a class="stage_link" href="#">Send or Schedule</a>
      </li>
      <div class="clr"></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not useful. See how the animation lets ball to fall down on hover!

Answer (score 0):

Cool :)

Add a CSS animation to your hover

```
.stage_not:hover .stage_circle {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes example {
  from {width:0px; border:none;}
  to {width:20px; border: 2px solid white;}
}
```

Clearly this needs some finessing, but a start at least.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to do minor changes in css for smooth experience. Here i am sharing what you need to change.

Add animation to "#stages li" css.

```
#stages li{
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
}
#stages li a{
    border: 6px solid #ffffff;
    margin: -13px auto 10px;
}
.stage_not:hover .stage_circle{
    background: #2585fe;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #d4d7df;
}
#stages li a + a{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```